# Making div appear from off-screen

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this assignment where I have to use pure javascript to make a `div` appear from the side of the screen without having the browser expand. This is what I have so far:

```js
function moveImg() {

  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

  var pos = 500;

  var id = setInterval(Move, 500);

  function Move() {
    if (pos <= 0) {
      clearInterval(id);

    } else {
      pos++;
      div.style.right = pos + 'px';
      div.style.top = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}

moveImg()
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Anyway i could make the div appear without expanding the page?

Comment: Where are you wanting it to start? (off the screen to the left, or at an angle, etc)

Comment: position of your div is `static` that's why it's not moving!

Comment: i wanted it to start off the bottom  right angle of the screen to about the middle

Comment: @potatohabib, so you want it to start from the bottom right of the viewport and move diagonally until it reaches the middle? That requires a bit more work...

Comment: @Chris yeah but i'll get it to work, thanks for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what was said in the comments, you don't say in what direction you want your `div` to move, nor from which position it should start.

I've set the starting position of top:100, left:100 and reducing the `top` and `left` values by `1px` each second:

```js
  function moveImg() {
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
  var pos = 100;
  var id = setInterval(Move, 500);

 function Move() {
   if (pos <= 0) {
     clearInterval(id);
   } else {
     pos--;
     div.style.left = pos + 'px';
     div.style.top = pos + 'px';
   }
  }
}

moveImg()
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a mill, it was wrecking my head. The code works beautifully

Comment: Great, please consider marking the question as solved, if it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use transform generally.

I've done some maths too, I've commented to code but feel free to ask if there's anything you need help understanding.

```js
function moveImg() {
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

  var posX = document.body.clientWidth - div.offsetWidth; // start position for X
  var posY = document.body.clientHeight - div.offsetHeight; // start position for Y
  var tarX = posX / 2; // end position for X
  var tarY = posY / 2; // end position for Y
  var time = 5; // how many seconds should the animation take
  var fps = 60; // frames per second, heigher is smoother but requires more power
  var stepX = ((posX - tarX) / (time * fps)); // how far X should move each frame
  var stepY = ((posY - tarY) / (time * fps)); // how far Y should move each frame

  var id = setInterval(Move, (1000 / fps));

  div.style.transform = "translate(" + posX + "px, " + posY + "px)";
  div.style.opacity = "1";

  function Move() {
    if (posX <= tarX && posY <= tarY) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      posX -= stepX;
      posY -= stepY;
      div.style.transform = "translate(" + posX + "px, " + posY + "px)";
    }
  }
}
moveImg();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background: tomato;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>Example!</div>
```